# Will the seals in a toilet dry out if the water is disconnected for a long period?

Tags: water

If we turn the main water off is it a problem for the seals in the toilet to dry out? We we be gone for a year, so over winter and summer..

Comment: Seals in the toilet ?   What seals ?

Comment: What state/climate is your home located? The list will vary drastically depending on climate.

Comment: a new toilet flapper is a lot cheaper than fixing flood damage.

Comment: Do you mean the seals inside the tank, or the large yellow wax seal under the toilet?

Answer (score 1):

There are several things to do before leaving a house for a year.  Try a quick search for "winterize a house" or something similar to find many checklists.  One list I saw mentioned pouring RV antifreeze down each of the drains to fill the P-trap, then putting stoppers in the drains and plastic wrap in the toilet bowl to help keep it from evaporating.

Answer (score 0):

I would shut the water off. If you are in a climate that could freeze, then winterize like Eric suggested.  Flushing so gaskets don't dry out was in an episode of Seinfeld: [Flush the toilets so gaskets don't dry out](https://memes.getyarn.io/yarn-clip/2eba8777-24c7-4779-b0f4-1245cda2939e)